# how can i prepare menu (arrays) for this code

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigation, nav

I am learning wordpress together with bootstrap and i don't kno how to prepare menu for following code :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
 <ul class="navbar-nav nav-dropdown nav-right" data-app-modern-menu="true">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link link text-black display-4" href="">Item 1</a></li>     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link link text-black display-4" href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link link text-black display-4" href="">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link link text-black display-4" href="">Item 4</a></li>
</ul> </div>
```

for this code i am using

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <?php
 wp_nav_menu(
        array(
        'menu'                 => 'primarym',
        'container'            => 'ul',
        'container_class'      => 'navbar-nav nav-dropdown nav-right',
        'menu_class'           => 'menu',
        'menu_id'              => 'primary-menu',
        'echo'                 => true,
    )
    ); ?>   
     </div>
```

which is not working in my templates, can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create custom walker. Just use additional argument and set the filters for nav_menu_css_class and nav_menu_link_attributes.

Please check below which help you.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <?php
 wp_nav_menu(
        array(
        'menu'                 => 'primarym',
        'container'            => 'ul',
        'container_class'      => '',
        'menu_class'           => 'navbar-nav nav-dropdown nav-right',
        'menu_id'              => 'primary-menu',
        'add_li_class'         => 'nav-item',
        'echo'                 => true,
    )
    ); ?>   
</div>
```

Notice the new 'add_li_class' argument.
And set the filters on functions.php

```
function add_additional_class_in_li($classes, $item, $args) {
    if(isset($args->add_li_class)) {
        $classes[] = $args->add_li_class;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_additional_class_in_li', 1, 3);


function add_additional_class_in_ancher($atts) {
  $atts['class'] = "nav-link link text-black display-4";
  return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_additional_class_in_ancher');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close with your [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), just keep in mind that `container` is for the menu's container (in your case, the `div` tag) and `menu` is for the menu itself (in your case, the `ul` tag).
For those two elements, you'll have to set your arguments to:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu'            => 'primarym', // or the id of the menu (you could otherwise use theme_location)
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_id'    => 'navbarSupportedContent',
        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav nav-dropdown nav-right',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="%2$s" data-app-modern-menu="true">%3$s</ul>',
        'walker'          => new My_Walker(),
    )
);
```

You'll notice that there's a new `walker` argument, without which you won't be able to display the menu element itself (`li` and `a` tags) the way you want.

A [walker](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) is a core class used to implement an HTML list of nav menu items and here's how you could use it for your example :

```
class My_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth, $args ) {
    }
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        // $output : var returned at the end of the walker
        // $item : information about the current item
        $output .= sprintf(
            '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link link text-black display-4" href="%1$s">%2$s',
            $item->url,
            $item->title
        );
    }
    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        // $output : var returned at the end of the walker
        $output .= '</a></li>';
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth, $args ) {
    }
}
```